# How to secure copy using Puppet?

Tags: unix, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have been trying to copy a directory from my master to different hosts. I have a script that checks out a code and puts it in certain directory. 
My script looks like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
export CVSROOT=:pserver:anonymous@server101:2401/cvs/PXI/
cvs checkout -r 2_a Jcode
mv  Jcode /etc/example/puppettest/
```

Now I want to copy this Jcode to my hosts.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to get what you are trying to do to work, but have you considered file buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to copy `/etc/example/puppettest` to your nodes you would have to create a mount point in `${configdir}/fileserver.conf` then you can use the `recurse` parameter of the `file` resource.

This following has not been tested:

#### ${configdir}/fileserver.conf

```
[jcode]
  path /etc/example/puppettest/
  allow *
```

#### file declaration

```
file { '/path/to/directory/on/node':
  ensure  => directory,
  recurse => true,
  source  => 'puppet:///jcode/Jcode'
}
```

Comment: And how long will it take to get copied to the nodes? Will it be automatically copied within 30 minutes of the time when I update something on /etc/example/puppettest ?

Comment: whenever the next puppet run occurs... and however long it takes to copy the actual data over the network...

Comment: It worked, but it's not auto updating. For e.g. if I add a file inside my host directory, I don't see it getting copied automatically, and I have to run it manually every time. Any ideas on that?

Comment: that is how puppet works.... it will only make the change when puppet is ran. if the puppet service is running then the runs usually occur in 30 minute intervals. you can just run the puppet agent yourself, or use something like mcollective to orchestrate the runs.

Comment: the service is most likely running, but the agent run is not a CONSTANT thing. it by default checks in with the master every thirty minutes. If your trying to treat the puppet fileserver like a network share then i think you are taking the wrong approach.

Comment: The problem is solved btw. The host puppet service was stopped due to some reason. I have no idea how/why/when.