# How do I define the directory in init.pp?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

My init.pp looks like below:

```
class checkout {
 file { '/etc/example/test/testcv.sh':
ensure   => present,
owner => 'root',
mode => '0755',
content => template('checkout/testcv.sh.erb')
}
}
```

What this does is, copies testcv.sh to my /etc/example/test/ in all my hosts automatically. But if I have to copy the directory to the certain location what resource type should I use? I tried replacing file with "dir" but it didn't work.

Comment: I think this may be a semi-duplicate of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069655/how-to-secure-copy-using-puppet

Comment: You are right. I asked both questions. I will delete this.                                            Update: Couldn't delete because it has been answered.

Comment: may want to except it as the answer then ;) (assuming it answered your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` resource is also used to create directories by changing the `ensure` parameter to `directory`.

```
file { '/etc/example/test':
  ensure => directory
  ...
  ...
}
```